# Do a TCP stream comprising SYNs and ACKs involve only one-time Ethernet packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, ethernet

I know this question sounds dumb but lately It's quite hard for my mind to visualize whole packet flow at Layer 2 level.

I'm developing a firewall at Layer 2 and interested at inspecting TCP packets while routing the packets back and forth.

But It's doubtful whether I could inspect the TCP stream as I can't confirm whether the TCP stream involve multiple Ethernet packets between the flow

I made attempts using Wireshark but to be honest, I'm lost at figuring out how to extract the whole stream..........

Comment: I assume you're talking about the response syn/ack to a syn sent by a remote host during a TCP 3-way handshake?

Comment: @AndyDalton No. I was talking about this three way handshake itself. I need to confirm whether three way handshake involve three Ethernet frames or just a single.

Comment: How could a message from A to B and a message from B to A be in a single Ethernet frame?

Comment: @ Andy Dalton The assumption I had is that TCP is a streaming protocol therefore single Ethernet frame is enough for connection initialization and the messaging done through TCP thereafter without anymore frames.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about what an "Ethernet frame" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is implemented agnostic of the data link layer. Thus, a TCP packet can span one or more ethernet frames.

If you want filter at the data link layer and inspect higher layers of the network communication as well, you will need to assemble the TCP communication manually from the composite data link frames, and then inspect the layer 3 information.

[Ethernet frames have standard sizes,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) so assembling packets from frames should not be that challenging, and you may find that most of the TCP handshaking steps themselves may fit inside a single ethernet frame, but if you happen to be working with an 802.11 media, this could become much more daunting since layer 2 can be encrypted between Wifi clients and access points.

Comment: It's not about parsing actually. I just need to know during a three way handshake, does there are three Ethernet frames or just one?